# Smooth collar sliding down smooth shaft

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, relative-motion

[image]

For part (a), we find that the acceleration of the collar is $6.94~\mathrm{m/s^2}$. In part (b), we say that the acceleration of B with respect to A is $6.94~\mathrm{m/s^2}$, which makes sense.

However, in part C, the acceleration of C with respect to A is not $6.94$ anymore. From what I understand, someone standing on A would see the collar C coming down at $6.94~\mathrm{m/s^2}$ but they get an answer of $5.522$. What is the logic behind this value and why is it not $6.94~\mathrm{m/s^2}$ (which is the value one would see IF THEY WERE SITTING ON A)?

Edit: No matter how fast or slow A is going, someone sitting on A would see the collar C coming down at the same acceleration of $6.94~\mathrm{m/s^2}$ no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

A is accelerating away from C.  Don't forget that C is not fixed to the smooth shaft, AB.  The shaft is accelerating away from C, which has to catch up with A.  So from the standpoint of A, C is accelerating slower.

Comment: Oh right, I was imagining C being fixed to the smooth shaft.